# Windows Backup Error

Tags: windows-8, windows-backup

Okay so I set up Windows 7 File Recovery and I keep getting the same result after backing up my computer I click on the "View skipped files" and it is always the same two files.

[image]

I keep getting these two errors:

> Backup encountered a problem while backing up file C:\Users\Acronis
>   Agent User\Contacts. Error:(The system cannot find the file specified.
>   (0x80070002)) Backup encountered a problem while backing up file
>   C:\Users\Acronis Agent User\Searches. Error:(The system cannot find
>   the file specified. (0x80070002))

It is true these two files do not exist, nor should they I have removed Acronis, why does Windows 7 File Recovery keep trying to back them up?

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to remove _Acronis Agent User_ in the list of users, and then remove its profile.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the files are hidden rather than removed?  Try just excluding the defunct Acronis folder.

Also, just a note, when you post a screenshot, try to capture just the window in question rather than the full screen.  While you have that error window selected, use Alt-PrtScreen (or Alt-Shift-PrtScreen if the PrtScreen functionality requires the Shift key too.)  This will capture just the active window, a lot smaller image.

Comment: I will let you know when I sit back down at the computer, also, I fixed the picture...